# Grouping with 3 tables in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, grouping

I am very new to LINQ and having great trouble grouping my tables so everything adds up together. I am trying to get this to display all the customers that have purchased more than $50 EVEN IF THEY HAVE MULTIPLE PURCHASES. in the SQL database using linq. Here is what I have so far, please help.

```
 public class TopCustomerVM
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal DollarsSold { get; set; }

    public static List<TopCustomerVM> GetResults()
    {
        ACEEntities db = new ACEEntities();
        return (from c in db.Customers
                join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                join l in db.OrderLines on o.OrderId equals l.OrderId

                into x
                select new TopCustomerVM {                           
                        Name = c.FirstName + c.LastName,
                        DollarsSold = x.Sum(asdf => asdf.UnitCost * asdf.Quantity)
                       })
                       .OrderByDescending(lkj => lkj.DollarsSold)
                       .Where(lkj => lkj.DollarsSold > 50)
                       .ToList();            
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to do it, but if you edit your post and add a carraige return after Please Help, the first part of your code will format properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will give you the desired output:

```
from record in 
    (from c in Customers
    join o in Orders on c.Id equals o.CustomerId
    join ol in OrderLines on o.Id equals ol.OrderId
    let customerAndLine = new { Name = c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName, DollarsSold = ol.UnitCost * ol.Quantity }
    group customerAndLine by customerAndLine.Name into grp  
    select new { Name = grp.Key, DollarsSold = grp.Sum(r => r.DollarsSold) })
where record.DollarsSold > 50
orderby record.DollarsSold descending
select record
```